# SQL - Assigning values from external table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have a two column table with customers' IDs and coupons. I would like to fill in the 'Coupon' column by assigning vouchers from an external data list to each customer's ID. What's more, once the code is assigned, it can't be assigned once again to the other customer.

Could you please help me write a SQL query for that?

```
Table:
| Customer ID | Coupon |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 100  |            |
| 200  |           |
| 300 |           |

Data list:
| Voucher ID | Voucher |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1   |      j2h3h2      |
| 2  |      hfd7s8     |
| 3  |    fsdfs72       |

Final result
| Customer ID | Coupon |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 100   |      j2h3h2      |
| 200  |      hfd7s8     |
| 300  |    fsdfs72       |
```

Comment: How should we determine which coupon is assigned to which customer?  Does the assignment have to be deterministic *(the same every time it is executed)*?  Will there *always* be enough coupons for one coupon per customer?  Can there ever be more coupons than customers?  Why does the final result include the coupon's string, rather than its id?

Comment: It doesn't matter which coupon is assigned to which customer. The coupons will be valid for each customer, but single customer should receive an individual coupon. Assignment should be done only for those customers who haven't got codes assigned yet, so the 'coupon' value is empty for their ID. 

Let's assume that there are enough coupons. It doesn't matter right now, I just want to test the mechanism. 

Yes, there are always more coupons than customers. The table with customers is updated every day so the coupons that weren't assigned previously should be assigned to the new customers.

Comment: We want to send the coupon's string to customers, that's why we use it instead of the ID.

Comment: Which Database Management System?  Syntac varies between them.  *(Hover your cursor over the `SQL` tag for more infomation.)*

Comment: Do you mean that - MySQL?

Comment: Which MySQL?  MySQL 5.x?  MySQL 8?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner when it comes to SQL. I want to write SQL procedure for Selligent Marketing Cloud. I'm not sure if it is a separate Database Management System or if they use MySQL. I think the syntax is standard.

Comment: A quick internet search seems to indicate that they host on the platform of your choice.  https://www.stitchdata.com/integrations/selligent/  As for `standard syntax`, there's no such thing.  The way I'd do it in Microsoft SQL Server won't work in MySQL, etc.  Contact your support staff and find out what this is hosted on.  Or reverse engineer it by trying different RDBMSes `get version` code.

Comment: It is MySQL 8.0 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As you've commented that you're using MySQL 8 I'll use Common Table Expressions and `ROW_NUMBER()` to create sequentially numbered rows.

I can then join them back to the table being updated, and to each other, to assign the new voucher id's to customers that don't have one.

I'll also use the term `voucher`, as you appear to have used voucher and coupon interchangeably.

```
WITH
  renumbered_customer AS
(
  -- Find all rows in the customer table that do Not have an assigned voucher
  -- Number those rows sequentially from 1 upwards
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY customer_id)   AS row_id
  FROM
    customer
  WHERE
    voucher_id IS NULL
),
  renumbered_voucher AS
(
  -- Find all rows in the voucher table that have not bee assigned to a customer
  -- Number those rows sequentially from 1 upwards
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY voucher_id)   AS row_id
  FROM
    voucher
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
        FROM customer
       WHERE customer.voucher_id = voucher.voucher_id
    )
)
UPDATE
  customer
INNER JOIN
  renumbered_customer  c
    ON c.customer_id = customer.customer_id
INNER JOIN
  renumbered_voucher   v
    ON c.row_id = v.row_id
SET
  customer.voucher_id = v.voucher_id
;
```

Working demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29875e64b3de3559ceea20d85d222f9b

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test it and let you know if it works :)